# How do I delete an alert from Microsoft Outlook that has been removed or deleted?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I am receiving a phantom alert from microsoft outlook that will not allow me to dismiss, postpone and or delete from the alerts.  If I click on either of those options I receive a popup that reads the object has been removed and I click ok.  Reminder comes back.

Comment: You might try your question on superuser.com. This question doesn't sound like a programming problem...

Answer (score 1):

Try to run Outlook.exe /cleanreminders.  If that does not work, we'd need to know what type of account you are connecting to. E.g. are you using Exchange?